# Open links using vba without FollowHyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink, runtime-error

On my vba procedure, I have `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=link` but "Link" is often too big for the function to use because "link" could hold string values as big as a small paragraph and this causes me to have a run-time error. It works with links with smaller string size but the with the big ones, if fails with this exact error below

[image: error]

Is there another way to open links using vba that could handle big urls?

Comment: Could you share one of those links so we have something to test with?

Comment: the link is behind a private network on a government server so unfortunately I can't share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using API. It should accept the URL maximum string length (2048).

1. Copy the next code on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
```

2. Copy the next code in the standard module where the API function has been copied:

```
Sub testOpenURL
   ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, "http://www.your big string representing URL", vbNullString, vbNullString, 5
End Sub
```